# Custom UITextField like this

Tags: ios, uitextfield

[image]

I must custom UITextField like the image above, so i try to write my custom class extend UITextField class.
But my problem is: stroke shadow outline of rect, and set white background for textfield inside
my custom code is:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
 {
  // Drawing code
     self.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
     self.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
     CALayer *layer = self.layer;
     layer.cornerRadius = 15.0;
     layer.masksToBounds = YES;
     layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
     layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1] CGColor];
     [layer setShadowColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
     [layer setShadowOpacity:1];
     [layer setShadowOffset: CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0)];
     [self setClipsToBounds:NO];
     [self setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter];
     [self setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];
 }
  - (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
          return CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + 20, bounds.origin.y + 8,
                  bounds.size.width - 40, bounds.size.height - 16);
 }
 - (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
          return [self textRectForBounds:bounds];
 }
```

So my question is: what code i'm missing(here is set white background inside, set outline shadow for border) thanks for your helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you try this first?
`self.textField.background = myUIImage;

self.textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;`

Answer (score 0):

Use the image of the text field box, and put it behind a normal UITextField that is set to custom and is therefore transparent. That way you get the text field functionality and can put any sort of graphic behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i solved my problems after reading some tutorials, here is my code i've written

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

     self.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
     self.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
     CALayer *layer = self.layer;
     layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
     layer.cornerRadius = 15.0;
     layer.masksToBounds = YES;
     layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
     layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1] CGColor];
     [layer setShadowColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
     [layer setShadowOpacity:1];
     [layer setShadowOffset: CGSizeMake(0, 2.0)];
     [layer setShadowRadius:5];
     [self setClipsToBounds:NO];
     [self setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter];
     [self setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];
  }
  - (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
        return CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + 20, bounds.origin.y + 8,
                  bounds.size.width - 40, bounds.size.height - 16);
   }
  - (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
        return [self textRectForBounds:bounds];
   }
```